# Can you check my codes because when I mouse out the image; the image shows a reflection on the other side. How can I get rid of it?

Tags: html, css

This is my HTML code:

```
 <a href="url/RollBearing.html" id="various2">
 <img class="rollingbearingdefects" src="img/hotspot.png"
    onmouseover="this.src='img/RollingBearingDefects2.png';"
    onmouseout="this.src='img/hotspot.png';" /></a>
```

This is my CSS code:

```
 .rollingbearingdefects{
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:-22%;
    margin-top:30%;
 }


 @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .rollingbearingdefects {
       max-width:3%;
       max-height:6%;
       position:absolute;
       margin-left:-22%;
       margin-top:30%;
    }
 }

.rollingbearingdefects:hover {
    margin-left:-35%;
 }

 @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
   .rollingbearingdefects:hover {
       max-height:6%;
       max-width:17%;
    }
 }
```

Comment: This is the html code:
<a href="url/RollBearing.html" id="various2">
 <img class="rollingbearingdefects" src="img/hotspot.png"
  onmouseover="this.src='img/RollingBearingDefects2.png';"
  onmouseout="this.src='img/hotspot.png';" /></a>

Comment: Is it possible to set it up in a JSFiddle and show us? http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Or edit your question and make a snippet. The problem is that I don't know how it's supposed to work; I made [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pefq0s3p/), but the image in question is positioned off screen!